# Combine PHP array conditionally

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine values from an array to be output into another array as a single flattened value  rather than another array. My problem is the final output is always another array, while what I need is to append the other value into the first value using a dash (-), and so on depending on its presence:

If all is present, should output a-b-c, if two of either combination = a-b, a-c, b-c, otherwise simply a or b or c

```
  $classes = array('a', 'b', 'c');

  foreach ($classes as $class) {
    if (!empty($block[$class])) {
      // If all is present, should output a-b-c, if two = a-b, a-c, b-c, otherwise simply a or b or c
      $variables['classes_array'][] = ....;
    }
  }
```

Comment: why not just write that in an if statement?

Comment: Looks like [array_intersect_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) might help you with what you want...

Comment: Thanks, I used implode, seems to work, but still it generated the unneeded ones: a, b-c, a-b-c are all output when all is present, while all I need is just a-b-c :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do what you want:

```
$classes = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );

$variables = array();

foreach( $classes as $class ) {

    if( in_array( $class, $block ) ){
        $variables[] = $class;
    }

}

$variables  = implode( '-', $variables );

echo $variables;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is fine now. I imploded inside the loop which held the issue. Yours clarify it really well.